# Cross Platform C++ IMAP Library

Tags: open-source, email, imap

Are there any cross-platform (only interested in Windows and OS X) IMAP libraries which I can use from C++?  Preferably open source as well.

I am currently using the IMAP library from Chilkat, but this is Windows only.

I've found libEtPan and VMime and just wondered if there were any others I could look at to compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [VMIME](http://www.vmime.org/)?

It has all my favorite things in a library:

1. Free, as in free beer
2. Free, as in free speech (Open Source also)
3. Regularly updated (very important)
4. Decent (though not great) documentation
5. Portable

Comment: Think I'll take another look at VMime, I'm sure it will do what I want.

Comment: Be careful, gplv3, that's very restrictive for a library (viral part of GPL).

Comment: There's a commercial license available for 99 euros. Seems quite reasonable if you're developing commercial software.

Comment: Yet quite unreasonable if you're doing free non-gpl software.  GPL libraries are a really bad thing, because of the 'viral' part of GPL.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz Does it support proxy ? and fetching of custom imap extension ?

Comment: commercial licenses now start at 199 euros

Comment: They raised the price again to 250 euros.

Comment: Checkout GNU mailutils, seems comprehensive

Comment: The price is now raised again to 549 euro.  
Also remember the LGPL like license is not useable for signed store applications.

Comment: Please when describing gplv3 as "viral" give some link to what is suffering from this so-called "viral"ness.  GPL is _needed_ to protect the safety and freedom of users, and is _not_ in prevention of profit or license -restricted code.  This protection is not a bad thing like a virus is.

Answer (score 7):

Another good choice can be [cURL library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) which is C library but it has C++ bindings - [cURLpp](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/).

The best thing is that it is licensed under the MIT license which perfectly fits for the commercial use or a non-opensource projects.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives are [libetpan](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan) (a C language library) and Mailcore (a C++ wrapper for libetpan)

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit dated since it's development has stopped being open-source, you can check the [UW-IMAP toolkit](http://www.washington.edu/imap/). However, its primary author continues development of the toolkit under the name Panda-IMAP and makes it available to anyone who wishes to donate for the development of the project.

Comment: Its primary author died about a year ago.

Comment: Yes and now the latest version of Panda IMAP is available via github https://github.com/jonabbey/panda-imap