# C++ IMAP Library for Downloading emails

Tags: c++, email, gmail, imap

Does anyone know of a good free c++ imap Library.  Trying to download and extract all emails from my gmail account with attachments.  Then I would like to process the attachments I will be sending to it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1796472/440558

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/), but [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) also has IMAP features, I believe (and C++ bindings).